# Drupal 6 / Views / XSS-SQL Injection

Tags: 6, views

First, let me start off by saying I have never worked with Drupal before. I've never even so much as looked at it. So forgive me if I'm asking obvious or rudimentary questions.

Yesterday, we were notified via a very kind customer of a potential SQL injection / XSS attack in one of our websites (by 'our' I mean a site run by a marketing team here with little interaction from IS or the DBA groups). After looking at it and testing it is indeed a problem and I was tasked with going about resolving the issue.

Screenshot time!

The problem.

[image: URL]

Unescaped user input.

Which then spits out on the actual web page:

[image: Output]

Now, from what I've gathered from talking to our marketing team that manages this, there's a concept of views in Drupal that they use to build up this query. I dug in and here's what I see for the page in question.

[image: View]

Now, I'm unsure if this filter parameter is even related to the view or if this is some separate functionality I'm unaware of. Can anyone out there more versed in Drupal point me in the right direction to escape this input. I was hoping I could have just opened a query and thrown an escape function on the parameters but it seems I'm going to have to dig in a bit more.

Comment: This probably belongs on Drupal answers.

Comment: While I think the problem you're reporting here has already been fixed in Views, you should still never publicly report potential security issues. Rather, follow the instructions here: http://drupal.org/node/101494

Answer (score 3):

I would check your versions, drupal will tell you if there are any security announcements for the current version. Login and go to /admin/reports/status

The other thing worth noting is that you should look at the page display (the second link from the top on the left) I'm not convinced that you have an SQL injection going on there  `<bad%` is just a string in the query there is plenty of filtering that goes on in drupals internals against this.

Comment: Checking that, it's listed at Drupal 6.1.3. Is there a straight foward way of checking the version of the View module? EDIT: Found module versioning page. As for the SQL injection, we verified that it indeed was vulnerable. We inject a malformed filter param value that ran an arbitrary query that returned a list of all the tables in the database

Comment: 6.1.3 is very old (current is 6.20) that should be upgraded. If you go to admin/reports/updates you can see what modules need to be updated

Comment: Thanks for the info. At the very least I've made the recommendation to get our installation current.